# How to implement stdp in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement STDP (Spike-Timing Dependent Plasticity) in tensorflow. It's a bit complicated. Any ideas (to get running entirely within a tensorflow graph)?

It works like this: say I have 2 input neurons, and they connect to 3 output neurons, via this matrix: `[[1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]` (input neuron 0 connects to output neurons 0 and 1...).

Say I have these spikes for the input neurons (2 neurons, 7 timesteps):

```
Input Spikes:
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

And these spikes for the output neurons (3 neurons, 7 timesteps):

```
Output Spikes:
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Now, for each non-zero weight, I want to compute a dw. For instance, for input neuron 0 connecting to output neuron 0:

The time stamps of the spikes for input neuron 0 are `[2, 3, 5]`, and the timestamps for output neuron 0 are `[3, 6]`. Now, I compute all the delta times:

```
Delta Times = [ 2-3, 2-6, 3-3, 3-6, 5-3, 5-6 ] = [ -1, -4, 0, -3, 2, -1 ]
```

Then, I compute some function (the actual STDP function, which isn't important for this question - some exponential thing)

```
 dw = SUM [ F(-1), F(-4), F(0), F(-3), F(2), F(-1) ]
```

And that's the dw for the weight connecting input neuron 0 to output neuron 0. Repeat for all non-zero weights.

So I can do all this in numpy, but I'd like to be able to do it entirely within a single tensorflow graph. In particular, I'm stuck on computing the delta times. And how to do all this for all non-zero weights, in parallel.

This is the actual stdp function, btw (the constants can be parameters):

```
def stdp_f(x):
    return tf.where(
        x == 0, np.zeros(x.shape), tf.where(
            x > 0, 1.0 * tf.exp(-1.0 * x / 10.0), -1.0 * 1.0 * tf.exp(x / 10.0)))
```

---

A note on performance: the method given by @jdehesa, below, is both correct and clever. But it also turns out to be slow. In particular, for a real neural network of 784 input neurons feeding into 400 neurons, over 500 time steps, the `spike_match =` step performs multiplication of (784, 1, 500, 1) and (1, 400, 1, 500) tensors.

Comment: Just to be clear about the shapes, you have input spikes, `NxT`, output spikes, `MxT` and, ultimately, you want `dw` with shape `NxM`, each element being the sum of the STDP function for each pairwise difference, is that right? Or should I add an additional first "batch" dimension?

Comment: that is correct - output is N x M

Comment: @Colin Hi Colin, trying something similar myself! Where did you get your T (Tau) value as 10 from within your STDP equation?

Comment: I think I made it up. No idea what it is in biological systems. I bet it varies a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with STDP, so I hope I understood correctly what you meant. I think this does what you describe:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def f(x):
    # STDP function
    return x * 1

def stdp(input_spikes, output_spikes):
    input_shape = tf.shape(input_spikes)
    t = input_shape[-1]
    # Compute STDP function for all possible time difference values
    stdp_values = f(tf.cast(tf.range(-t + 1, t), dtype=input_spikes.dtype))
    # Arrange in matrix such that position [i, j] contains f(i - j)
    matrix_idx = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(t - 1, 2 * t - 1), 1) + tf.range(0, -t, -1)
    stdp_matrix = tf.gather(stdp_values, matrix_idx)
    # Find spike matches
    spike_match = (input_spikes[:, tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis] *
                   output_spikes[tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis, :])
    # Sum values where there are spike matches
    return tf.reduce_sum(spike_match * stdp_matrix, axis=(2, 3))

# Test
input_spikes = [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
output_spikes = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    ins = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
    outs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
    res = stdp(ins, outs)
    res_val = sess.run(res, feed_dict={ins: input_spikes, outs: output_spikes})
    print(res_val)
    # [[ -7.  10. -15.]
    #  [-13.   7. -24.]]
```

Here I assume that `f` is probably expensive (and that its value is the same for every pair of neurons), so I compute it only once for every possible time delta and then redistribute the computed values in a matrix, so I can multiply at the pairs of coordinates where the input and output spikes happen.

I used the identity function for `f` as a placeholder, so the resulting values are actually just the sum of time differences in this case.

EDIT: Just for reference, replacing `f` with the STDP function you included:

```
def f(x):
    return tf.where(x == 0,
                    tf.zeros_like(x),
                    tf.where(x > 0,
                             1.0 * tf.exp(-1.0 * x / 10.0),
                             -1.0 * 1.0 * tf.exp(x / 10.0)))
```

The result is:

```
[[-3.4020822   2.1660795  -5.694256  ]
 [-2.974073    0.45364904 -3.1197631 ]]
```

Comment: Wow. Impressive. And basically all the hard work can be precomputed! I added the actual stdp function in the question for reference...

Comment: @Colin Thanks, I added the result with the actual function.

Comment: you sure? I'm getting values that are always +1 from yours - maybe you had a 1.0 + when it should have been 1.0 *?

Comment: If I take my initial snippet but replace the `f` function with the function in my second snippet I get the result in my third snippet. Are you getting something different? Or should the result be something else?